# Run javascript from php file

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have this table which I fill with php variables and also create in my php code. Between every row I create I want to execute some javascript. So before the creation of a new row I try to execute some javascript. But for some reason the javascript just doesn't execute. The table gets created just fine. This is my code:

functions.php (the code I use to fill my table)

```
        while ($result->fetch()) 
        {
            $htmlString .= "<script>document.write('Test');</script>";                 
            $htmlString .= "<tr>";
            $htmlString .= "<td>". $i ."</td>";
            $htmlString .= "<td>". $name ."</td>";
            $htmlString .= "<td>". $condition ."</td>";
            $htmlString .= "</tr>";             
            $i++;               
        }           
        echo $htmlString;
```

Comment: What does you page source say? Also, but I'm not 100% sure, I don't know if there can be javascript executed as soon as you also specify a file...

Comment: `<script>` is not allowed between `<table>` and `<tr>`. Otherwise you cannot mix `src`-attribute _and_ inline code in `<script>`

Comment: When I inspect the page with google chrome. I can see the script between every row. But I never see the text "test" on the page itself.

Comment: @fboes You were right. Problem solved. If you use your comment as an answer I will accept it as an answer.

Comment: @ArabCheese Very well, I posted it as an answer for everyone's pleasure :)

Comment: Please stop doing dreadful things like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding the javascript to the `$htmlString` I just echo it right away. So now I can replace the `document.write('Test')` with the real javascript I wanted to execute:

```
while ($result->fetch()) 
{
    echo "<script>document.write('Test');</script>";                 
    $htmlString .= "<tr>";
    $htmlString .= "<td>". $i ."</td>";
    $htmlString .= "<td>". $name ."</td>";
    $htmlString .= "<td>". $condition ."</td>";
    $htmlString .= "</tr>";             
    $i++;
}               
echo $htmlString;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot print text between two table rows. Try this:

```
    while ($result->fetch()) 
    {
        $htmlString .= "<tr><td colspan=\"3\"><script>document.write('Test');</script></td></tr>";                 
        $htmlString .= "<tr>";
        $htmlString .= "<td>". $i ."</td>";
        $htmlString .= "<td>". $name ."</td>";
        $htmlString .= "<td>". $condition ."</td>";
        $htmlString .= "</tr>";             
        $i++;               
    }
```

Comment: Actually the printing the text is just a test. Normally I would like to populate a javascript array. But this doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible for the php code to produce an HTML/JS page that, when it reaches the browser and the browser has interpreted it then it runs your javascript code, but it's *not possible* to write javascript to be interpreted while you are still generating your page via PHP server-side. If possible, you have to write the 'javascript functionality' server side using PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

`<script>` is not allowed between `<table>` and `<tr>`. And as the script tries to insert HTML at this point, it stops doing so for being invalid HTML. I reccomend using `console.log('Test');` instead.

Otherwise you cannot mix `src`-attribute and inline code in `<script>`